# Beautifulsoup span class is returning a blank string

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print out different things from a Norwegian weather site with beautifulsoup.
I manage to print out everything i want except one thing witch mentions how the weather will be the next hour.

This contains the text i want to get:

```
<span class="nowcast-description" data-reactid="59">har opphold nå, det holder seg tørt den neste timen</span>
```

And i am trying print it with this:

```
cond = soup.find(class_='nowcast-description').get_text()
```

[Inspected elements from storm.no/ski](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL5e6.png)

Here is a picture of the some of the elements on the site.

with printing these:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
loc = soup.find(class_='info-text').get_text()
cond = soup.find(class_='nowcast-description').get_text()
temp = soup.find(class_='temperature').get_text()
wind = soup.find(class_='indicator wind').get_text()
```

also tested with this line:

```
cond = soup.select("span.nowcast-description")
```

but that gives me everything except what i want from the line.

Site link: https://www.storm.no/ski

i get:

Ski Akershus, 131 moh.

""

2°

3 m/s

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: I tried to add it now. the line is just blank in powershell

Comment: Can you share us the link?

Comment: Yes, that is https://www.storm.no/ski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is retrieved dynamically from a script tag. You can regex out object containing all forecasts and handle with hjson library due to unquoted keys. You need to install hjson then do the following:

```
import requests, hjson, re

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.storm.no/ski')
p = re.compile(r'window\.__dehydratedState = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
data = hjson.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
print(data['app-container']['current']['forecast']['nowcastDescription'])
```

You could regex out with library direct as well but using hsjon means you have access to all the other data.

Comment: Is hjon something new interface?

Comment: @KunduK hsjon is a library that has been around a long time. Very useful for those less co-operative javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's because text under nowcast-description is generated dynamically. If you will dump the loaded page:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

You only find only this:

```
<span class="nowcast-description" data-reactid="59">
</span>
```

On rough analysis, it seems that the content of this span is loaded from field *nowcastDescription* which is a part of *window.__dehydratedState* . 
Because the field is a simple json, you can try to extract it from it.